# spring kafka 1.2.2 gracefull shutdown

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring kafka 1.2.2.RELEASE. Currently I have configured retry template for container that has no BackOffPolicy and AlwaysRetryPolicy. Ack mode is MANUAL_IMMEDIATE.

When a SIGTERM, I will let the current message to be processed and when @KafkaListener is called again with a new message I throw RuntimeException on container that retries indefinitely and throws exception continuously. And after some time SIGKILL is issued and container is stopped(I think there is a better way to do it). But with this process the message that was was retried is retrieved after the restart by consumer but is committed without calling KafkaListener. See offset=13 in below stack trace

Stack trace:

```
[20 May 2018 22:37:20] [ INFO] [] [ConsumerCoordinator  onJoinComplete]:[262 ] - Setting newly assigned partitions [messages-0] for group listener
[20 May 2018 22:37:20] [DEBUG] [] [KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$2 onPartitionsAssigned]:[513 ] - Committing on assignment: {messages-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=13, metadata=''}}
[20 May 2018 22:37:20] [ INFO] [] [AbstractMessageListenerContainer$2 onPartitionsAssigned]:[278 ] - partitions assigned:[messages-0]
[20 May 2018 22:37:20] [DEBUG] [] [KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer        run]:[632 ] - Received: 0 records
[20 May 2018 22:37:20] [DEBUG] [] [KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer        run]:[632 ] - Received: 1 records
[20 May 2018 22:37:20] [TRACE] [] [KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer doInvokeWithRecords]:[931 ] - Processing ConsumerRecord(topic = messages, partition = 0, offset = 13, CreateTime = 1526855737241, serialized key size = 31, serialized value size = 2032, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = "some key", value = "some random data")
[20 May 2018 22:37:20] [DEBUG] [] [KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer ackImmediate]:[749 ] - Committing: {messages-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=14, metadata=''}
```

And Is there a better way to stop container when I see SIGTERM is issued so @KafkaListener is not called with messages. I know that later versions(>2.0.0) of spring-kafka has KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry that can stop all consumers. But it is not currently possible to upgrade to 2.0.0.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint registry has been there since 1.0. 1.x users are recommended to upgrade to the latest 1.3.x; see [here](https://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/#compat).

When stopping the container from a listener it's better to do it on a new thread or the stop will be delayed.

See the 2.1.x [ContainerStoppingErrorHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerStoppingErrorHandler.java#L53) for how to do that. But, of course, you don't need to throw an exception after stopping.

But with 1.x, you will need to discard any subsequent messages that were already fetched.

Comment: Thanks Gary.  I just discovered that registry is available in 1.3.5. For example my Listener is slow and is still processing message. And I issue a sigterm to stop all containers(in another thread using registry).I'm not getting the same message back when I restart. Would you mind sharing you though on how to overcome this(I tried not to acknowledge message but still is the same). How to discard the message in KafkaListener

Comment: I found the issue. I was using recordFilterStrategy and before starting to  process message, i was adding this record to metadatastore and that caused this abnormal behaviour. Should have checked it earlier. Sorry and Thanks.